Gitlab CI/CD automatically create merge request or merge changes to another branch
I'm trying to improve our CI/CD flow in the project.
Currently it looks like this:

Developer creates PR for development phase
Maintainer merges this PR
If maintainer wants to push changes further (to staging), he has to create PR manually
Maintainer merge this PR

I would like to improve this flow to allow maintainers to automatically create PRs to staging, or to merge these changes to staging as a step in CI/CD. So the flow would be something like this:

Developer creates PR to development
Maintainer merges that PR
If the changes work fine on development stage maintainer runs last stage in CI/CD which is merge to staging

I'm wondering if something like this is good practice and if it's possible in Gitlab CI/CD.

Can you elaborate on "If the changes work fine on development stage"? Is this something that the maintainer needs to do manually? Do you mean that if the PR is merged and the CI pipeline passes, then it should merge to staging?

Yes, it is something that maintainer checks manually.
I would like to give maintainer possibility to push PR for further stages.
